# Ubuntu 18.04.1/Bionic won't boot with AMDGPU

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, 18.04

I have faced a problem with my Ubuntu 18.04.1 because of AMDGPU.
I think that it broke something, because now Ubuntu is stuck at the loading screen and it keeps blinking with an output of something that is like starting user 121.

I have managed successfully to remove the AMDGPU and the AMDGPU Pro, but I couldn't remove the AMDGPU core and I can't install anything.

The terminal outputs broken packages with missing dependencies. I tried everything to fix the broken packages, but I couldn't, so can anyone help me?

I don't want to re-format my PC, because I have a lot of "hecking" work on it.
I know that's a lot of "hecking" words 
(thanks in advance ~Exo)

Comment: Not a lot of word but the format could be improved, a lot. Please [edit] and make paragraphs and proper sentences with proper punctuation. Also the Ubuntu release version is 18.04.1.